# How does django really handle multiple requests on development server?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am making a little django app to serve translations for my react frontend. The way it works is as follows:

1. The frontend tries to find a translation using a key.
2. If the translation for that key is not found, It sends a request to the backend with the missing key
3. On the backend, the missing key is appended to a json file

Everything works just fine when the requests are sent one at a time (when one finishes, the other is sent). But when **multiple requests are sent at the same time**, everything breaks. The json file gets corrupted. It's like all the requests are changing the file at the same time which causes this to happen. I am not sure if that's the case because I think that the file can not be edited by two processes at the same time(correct me if I am wrong) but I don't receive such an error which indicates that the requests are handled one at a time according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49213647/how-does-django-handle-multiple-requests) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30506282/how-does-django-handle-multiple-users)

Also, I tried something, *which to my surprise worked*, that is to add `time.sleep(1)` to the top of my `api view`. When I did this, everything worked as expected.

What is going on ?

Here is the code, just in case it matters:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def save_missing_translation_keys(request, lng, ns):
    time.sleep(1)

    missing_trans_path = MISSING_TRANS_DIR / f'{lng}.json'

    # Read lng file and get current missing keys for given ns
    try:
        with open(missing_trans_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as missing_trans_file:
            if is_file_empty(missing_trans_path):
                missing_keys_dict = {}
            else:
                missing_keys_dict = json.load(missing_trans_file)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        missing_keys_dict = {}
    except Exception as e:
        # Even if file is not empty, we might not be able to parse it for some reason, so we log any errors in log file
        with open(MISSING_LOG_FILE, 'a', encoding='utf-8') as logFile:
            logFile.write(
                f'could not save missing keys {str(list(request.data.keys()))}\nnamespace {lng}/{ns} file can not be parsed because\n{str(e)}\n\n\n')
        raise e

    # Add new missing keys to the list above.
    ns_missing_keys = missing_keys_dict.get(ns, [])
    for missing_key in request.data.keys():
        if missing_key and isinstance(missing_key, str):
            ns_missing_keys.append(missing_key)
        else:
            raise ValueError('Missing key not allowed')

    missing_keys_dict.update({ns: list(set(ns_missing_keys))})

    # Write new missing keys to the file
    with open(missing_trans_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as missing_trans_file:
        json.dump(missing_keys_dict, missing_trans_file, ensure_ascii=False)

    return Response()
```

Comment: You have to make sure that no two threads or processes write to the same file at the same time. This is not a Django problem, the rules applies generally. You can use a lock (with a lockfile for production setups with multiple processes) or use sometime more thread-safe like a database with transportations.

Comment: This app is not intended for production. I am making it so it could help me internationalize my frontend because the other solutions I see are expensive for me.
I actually just tried using the database instead of files and It worked just fine. But I really want to know why it doesn't work with files. Can you tell me more about locking and thread safe apps (links)

Comment: You should educate yourself on how to write thread-safe applications. The topic is too extensive to be explained here.

Comment: Ok. I will look into that